# Ajax call fails immediately with textStatus: error and HTTP status 0 on Cordova, in ios

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova, whitelist

I've been working with this has been 3 weeks, and still no solution. So what happens is that I'm using Cordova and my ajax calls return immediately after they're called. Immediately as the error message is just below the sending message in the logs. The HTTP status is always 0 and textStatus is 'error'. At first, whitelisting seemed to be the issue, but I've already added this to my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I've upgraded both the whitelist plugin and Cordova to their latests versions without any improvement (1.2.2 and 6.5.0 respectively).

I've come to suspect that this may happen because my server don't support ipv6, but I tried some random ajax call to a friend's server that does, and the result is the same. No regular error from their end, just the same, immediate message.

Error is a javascript data object like this:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I think I'm running out of options. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: That happened to me twice. I think that is issue with cordova itself don't know what is triggering it. I solved it by removing and adding platform again. if it doesn't work create a new project with same name and plugin and replace WWW folder with old one. it will work.

Comment: @ArpitVasani tried removing and adding platforms again, and then tried creating a brand new project and replacing my www folder. Nope. Still returning immediately as soon as the ajax is fired, as it was not an async call.

Comment: does your index.html have Content-Security-Policy ? if yes then try after commenting it because that could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a form add

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

the API call is getting cancelled because the form is reloading the page, before the API call results are back.